Best way to install unsupported package on debian?
I need to install a newer version of libfmt on Debian 11. This is for CI/CD, and since fmt can be used header-only, I figure it should be ok.
What's the best way to do this, with the least chance of breaking something? Should I add a newer repository to sources and use pinning to hold-back other packages? Should I use an ubuntu ppa? Should I try to upload a newer version of the debian package to a PPA?

Specifically regarding libfmt, Debian 11 ships libfmt7 for packages relying on it; since the current version ships libfmt10, you won’t break anything by backporting it (libfmt7 will remain installed if it’s needed).
